# SQLlite Database is not visible in DDMS folder

Tags: android, virtualbox, ddms

I have setup virtual box for emulator, It is working fine but in DDMS I am unable to see the database that got created.

This kind of behaviour is because of virtual box or can we do any change so that we can see the database under data folder of DDMS

Please can anyone show me a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance
Siva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved.. Posting the answer so that anyone who has similar problem can refer and solve.

My virtual box doesn't have permissions so that "data" folder is disabled I have given the permission for read and write, After that I am able to see and export the database.

Method to give permission in virtual box:
1. go to CMD----> Folder where adb is present(Normally it is under Platform tools of SDK folder).

1. type **ADB Shell**
2. issue command to get root access **su -root**
3. issue command to the required folder **chmod -R 777 data/data/"required project"**

now you get the access to database under required project.

njoi.

Answer (score 0):

you must have root access to see databas. I think emulator should have it by default. Or not?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am doing by emulator instead I am using virtual box. If I use emulator I can see database in DDMS, problem is with virtual box.